# How to find number of occurences of specific distances in binary (search) trees?

Tags: binary-trees, probability-theory, search-trees, counting

I want to calculate the amount of tree structures that have a given maximal distance between two nodes given an amount `n` of nodes (or keys).

E.g. with `n = 3` there are 5 tree structures, each forced to have a maximal distance of two.
With `n = 4` I can build 14 structures, only 2 of which have a maximal distance of two. The other 12 have a maximal distance of 3.

Now, generalizing the question:

Is there a way to calculate the amount of tree structures with a maximal distance `d` given `n` nodes?
And what's the total probability that when given a (uniformly distributed) random permutation of keys to be inserted in the empty tree leads to one of the structures with maximal distance `d`?

Comment: I think you should stay consistent in your choice of _unlabelled_ and _labelled_ trees. In the first part of your question, you consider unlabelled objects (ie 5 and 14 instead of 6 and 24 cases), and then in the second part you talk about labelled binary trees. What are you looking for? Apart from that, you might want to consult _path length for trees_ in [Analytic Combinatorics](http://algo.inria.fr/flajolet/Publications/book.pdf).